# Vue.js - Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'lottie-vuejs'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to use `lottie-vuejs` in my project. I did the `npm` install and follow the guidance given here

https://www.npmjs.com/package/lottie-vuejs.

But I am getting

> `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'lottie-vuejs'.`

[Sample sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-albattani-emvic?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue:97-109)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to downgrade to the `0.3.6` version by uninstalling the current one :

```
 npm uninstall --save lottie-vuejs
```

and install the stable version `0.3.6` as follows :

```
 npm install lottie-vuejs@0.3.6
```

Comment: Thanks, not it resolved the module, but I still can't see the animation. Any idea?

Comment: give me the link

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-albattani-emvic?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Comment: @Brutus, did you get a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

the lottie-vuejs require other dependencies which is lottie-web and axios. You might need to include it as well. But I would suggest you staright away use the "lottie-web" package.
Here is the working example

https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-mendeleev-z0rkl?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue